Mongoose populate with array does not work
Hey so I am trying to populate meeting with trainee.name, which does not work and gets to the catch in the try catch block and returns 500. (using fastify+mongoose)
models/meeting.ts
    import uniqueValidator from 'mongoose-unique-validator';
    import { Schema, Types, model } from 'mongoose';
    
    interface MeetingType {
      _id: Types.ObjectId;
      coach: Types.ObjectId;
      trainees: Types.ObjectId[];
    }
    
    const meetingSchema = new Schema({
      coach: { type: Types.ObjectId, required: true, ref: 'Coach' },
      trainees: [{ type: Types.ObjectId, required: true, ref: 'Trainee' }],
not relevant info about meeting..

    });
    
    meetingSchema.plugin(uniqueValidator);
    
    const Meeting = model('meeting', meetingSchema);
    
    export default Meeting;
    
    export type { MeetingType };

models/trainee.ts
import uniqueValidator from 'mongoose-unique-validator';
import { Schema, Types, model } from 'mongoose';

interface TraineeType {
trainee's interface...
}

const traineeSchema = new Schema({
  name: { type: String, required: true },
  email: { type: String, required: true, unique: true, match: /@/ },
  meetings: [{ type: Types.ObjectId, required: true, ref: 'Meeting' }],
  activeCoachDetails: {
    activeCoach: { type: Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Coach' },
    startDateCoach: { type: Date },
  },
not relevant info about trainee..
});

traineeSchema.plugin(uniqueValidator);

const Trainee = model('trainee', traineeSchema);

export default Trainee;

export type { TraineeType };

and I have get pending meetings function, which sending the meetings correctly, but when I try to add the populate it sends 500 and crashes to catch block. without populate it works. I want populate to return trainee.name
controller.ts
const getPendingApprovalMeetings = async (
  request: any,
  reply: FastifyReply,
) => {
  const { coachId }: { coachId: string } = request.user;
  const { page, limit }: { page: number; limit: number } = request.query;
  let coach: CoachType | null;
  try {
    coach = await Coach.findById(coachId);
  } catch (err: Error | any) {
    logger.error(`can't get coach by his id: ${err.message} - ${coachId}`);
    return await reply
      .status(500)
      .send('Getting meetings failed, please try again.');
  }

  if (!coach) {
    logger.error(`didn't find coach by his id - ${coachId}`);
    return await reply
      .status(404)
      .send('Could not find coach for provided id.');
  }

  let pendingApprovalMeetings = [];
  try {
    pendingApprovalMeetings = await Meeting.find(
      {
        _id: { $in: coach.meetings },
        status: 'Waiting for approval',
      },
      {},
      {
        skip: (page - 1) * limit,
        limit,
      },
    )
      .populate({
        path: 'trainee',
        select: 'name',
      })
  } catch (err: Error | any) {
    logger.error(`can't get pending approval meetings - ${coachId}`, err);
    return await reply
      .status(500)
      .send('Getting pending approval meetings failed, please try again.');
  }

  return await reply.status(200).send({
    meetings: pendingApprovalMeetings,
  });
};


First of all, you can see the error logged by the following call.
logger.error(`can't get pending approval meetings - ${coachId}`, err);

Secondly, there is a typo.
The model Meeting has a path "trainees", in populate it has been referred as "trainee". The character "s" is missed.
 .populate({
        path: 'trainee',
        select: 'name',
      })

Please correct it to
 .populate({
        path: 'trainees',
        select: 'name',
      })

Lastly, while checking the error logged, you may see an error message similar to this:
StrictPopulateError: Cannot populate path `xxxx` because it is not in your schema. Set the `strictPopulate` option to false to override.
    at getModelsMapForPopulate ....

Edit 1:
To get the errors logged by the NPM module winston displayed in console as well, please add a new transports as new transports.Console(). The respective code snippet enclosed below. While running jest tests, the same console output will be visible to the tester too.
const logger = createLogger({
  level: 'info',
  format: format.combine(
    format.timestamp({
      format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss',
    }),
    format.errors({ stack: true }),
    format.splat(),
    format.json()
  ),
  defaultMeta: { service: 'your-service-name' },
  transports: [
    //
    // - Write to all logs with level `info` and below to `quick-start-combined.log`.
    // - Write all logs error (and below) to `quick-start-error.log`.
    //
    new transports.File({ filename: 'quick-start-error.log', level: 'error' }),
    new transports.File({ filename: 'quick-start-combined.log' }),
    new transports.Console(),
  ],
});

Nodejs Winston logger - log output to both console and file

Thanks, but when changing to trainees also doesn't work. How can I see the logger output when using jest tests?

Hello @steve123, sorry for the inconvenienced caused. Please help me to know the NPM module which you use for logging.

I use winston for the logger

Hello @steve123, please the section edit 1 in the answer.
